# How to parse tree from TFS Test Plan

Tags: c#, tfs, tree, test-plan

Good day!

I try to parse tree on test plan tfs 2010.

So, i can get Test Plan:

```
var planOld = helperOldProject.GetTestPlan("TestProject", 10); // 10- id of test plan
ITestManagementTeamProject project1 = helperNewProject.GetProject(sourceserverurl,    sourceproject);
```

Then i create new Test Plan Programmatically:

```
//Create a Test Plan Programmatically
 ITestPlan planNew = project1.TestPlans.Create();
        planNew.Name = planOld.Name;
        planNew.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        planNew.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
        planNew.AreaPath = "TestArea";
        planNew.Description = planOld.Description;
        planNew.State = planOld.State;
        // other attributes: plan.AreaPath, plan.Description,plan.State
        planNew.Save();

        And then i need to parse RootSuite tree:

        var suiteOld = planOld.RootSuite;

        // Parse Root:

        IStaticTestSuite suiteNew = project1.TestSuites.CreateStatic();
         suiteNew.Title = suiteOld.Title;
         planNew.RootSuite.Entries.Add(suiteNew);

         foreach (var tcc in suiteOld.TestCases)
         {
             var tc = helperOldProject.teamProject.TestCases.Find(tcc.Id);
             var tc2 = helperNewProject.teamProject.TestCases.Create();

             tc2.Description = tc.Description;
             tc2.Owner = tc.Owner;
             tc2.Title = tc.Title;
             tc2.Save();
             suiteNew0.Entries.Add(tc2);
             planNew.Save();
         }
```

And then i need to parse SubTree:

```
          CreateSubTree(ref project1,ref planOld,ref planNew,ref helperOldProject,ref helperNewProject);

           public static void CreateSubTree(ref ITestManagementTeamProject project1,ref ITestPlan planOld, 
       ref ITestPlan planNew,ref Helper helperOldProject,ref Helper helperNewProject)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("SubSuites.Count: " + planOld.RootSuite.SubSuites.Count);
        foreach (ITestSuiteBase suiteOld in planOld.RootSuite.SubSuites)
        {
            IStaticTestSuite suiteNew = project1.TestSuites.CreateStatic();

            // planNew.RootSuite.SubSuites.Add(suiteNew);

            IStaticTestSuite staticSuiteOld = suiteOld as IStaticTestSuite;


            foreach (ITestSuiteEntry tccOld in staticSuiteOld.TestCases)
            {
                suiteNew.Title = suiteOld.Title;
                planNew.RootSuite.Entries.Add(suiteNew);

                //planNew.RootSuite.SubSuites.Add(suiteNew);

                var tc = helperOldProject.teamProject.TestCases.Find(tccOld.Id);
                var tc2 = helperNewProject.teamProject.TestCases.Create();

                tc2.Description = tc.Description;
                tc2.Owner = tc.Owner;
                tc2.Title = tc.Title;
                tc2.Save();
                suiteNew.Entries.Add(tc2);

            }

            Console.WriteLine(suiteOld.TestSuiteEntry);
        }
    }
```

So, i parse new one subtree element, but i know,that after that node i have another one node.Like this:

Root:  element1,element2,element3 ...

--- Node1:element1,element2....

-------- Node2: element1,element2...

But  planOld.RootSuite.SubSuites.Count==1; And i see elements only of Root and Node1.

And another problem is to create new sub tree:
This code doesnt works:

```
planNew.RootSuite.SubSuites.Add(suiteNew);  // cannot add,remove item  error.
```

Please, help me to parse it! 
And why i cannot add sub node at tree?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can create a new test suite under a test plan

```
        ITestManagementTeamProject teamProject = testManagementService.GetTeamProject(projectId);
        ITestPlan testplan= teamProject.TestPlans.Find(testplanId);
        IStaticTestSuite newSuite = teamProject.TestSuites.CreateStatic();
        newSuite.Title = "new title";

        testplan.RootSuite.Entries.Add(newSuite);
        testplan.Save();
```

For the first question I dont really understand maybe you can explain more.